# Align image next to text html & css

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

I currently have this from my CSS & HTML:
[image]

However, I would like the image to align with the header text, like this:
[image]

How would i do this? I have floated the text to the left and the image to the right.

Here is my CSS & HTML

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#top_header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #26ABF5;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#logo_top {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 53px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

#main_nav {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-left: 150px;
}

#main_nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 6em;
}

.button {
  float: right;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 101px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #26abf5;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.banner {
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url('../images/Banner_bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.banner_header {
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 89px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 33px;
}

.banner_paragraph {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.priser_button {
  display: flex;
  width: 207px;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 400ms ease;
  transition: background-color 400ms ease;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  padding: 9px 0 9px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.priser_button:hover {
  background-color: #26abf5;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 84px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 53px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.underbanner_header {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.content_p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  max-width: 400px;
  float: left;
}

.image_content {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <header id="top_header">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="index.html"><img id="logo_top" draggable="false" src="images/logo1.png"></a>
          <nav id="main_nav">
            <a href="index.html">FORSIDE</a>
            <a href="#">HVAD TILBYDER VI?</a>
            <a href="#">PRISER</a>
            <a href="#">OM OS</a>
          </nav>
            <a class="button" href="#">LOG IND</a>
        </div>
      </header>

        <div class="banner">
          <h2 class="banner_header">DANMARKS FEDESTE FITNESS CENTER</h2>
          <p class="banner_paragraph">BLIV EN DEL AF TEAMET I DAG</p>
          <div class="container"><a class="priser_button" href="#">SE VORES PRISER</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="underbanner">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h3 class="underbanner_header">NYT CENTER I SØNDERBORG</h3>
        <p class="content_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. Duis cursus, mi quis viverra ornare, eros dolor interdum nulla, ut commodo diam libero vitae erat. Aenean faucibus nibh et justo cursus id rutrum lorem imperdiet. Nunc ut sem vitae risus tristique posuere.</p>
        <img src="images/content1.jpg" class="image_content"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text, move the `float: left` from `.content_p` to the wrapper (`underbanner_content`) and give the image the same margin top (`margin-top: 60px;`)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#top_header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #26ABF5;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#logo_top {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 53px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
#main_nav {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-left: 150px;
}
#main_nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 6em;
}
.button {
  float: right;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 101px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #26abf5;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.banner {
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url('../images/Banner_bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.banner_header {
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 89px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 33px;
}
.banner_paragraph {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.priser_button {
  display: flex;
  width: 207px;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 400ms ease;
  transition: background-color 400ms ease;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  padding: 9px 0 9px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.priser_button:hover {
  background-color: #26abf5;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 84px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.logo {
  width: 53px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.underbanner_content {
  float: left;
}
.underbanner_header {
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.content_p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.image_content {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="underbanner">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="underbanner_content">
        <h3 class="underbanner_header">NYT CENTER I SØNDERBORG</h3>
        <p class="content_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. Duis cursus, mi quis viverra ornare, eros dolor interdum nulla, ut commodo diam libero vitae erat. Aenean faucibus nibh et justo cursus
          id rutrum lorem imperdiet. Nunc ut sem vitae risus tristique posuere.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150" class="image_content" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a few changes:

```
.col_50{
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
}

.underbanner_header {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.image_content {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

<div class="underbanner">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col_50">
      <h3 class="underbanner_header">NYT CENTER I SØNDERBORG</h3>

      <p class="content_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. Duis cursus, mi quis viverra ornare, eros dolor interdum nulla, ut commodo diam libero vitae erat. Aenean faucibus nibh et justo cursus id rutrum lorem imperdiet. Nunc ut sem vitae risus tristique posuere.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col_50">
      <img src="images/content1.jpg" class="image_content"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```